# MySQL: Selecting all columns in a table plus one column from the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with many columns let say column1,....,column20. I don't want to scroll everytime to the end of the result table to see the value of column20.  In mssql I usually do
`SELECT column20, * FROM TABLE` but apparently this is not valid in MySQL. Any hints? (I also don't want to select all columns explicitly in the select statement)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to give the table name in your query, otherwise mysql complains :

```
SELECT column20, mytable.* FROM mytable
```

PS: I have absolutely no idea as to why, because `SELECT *, column20 FROM mytable` works just fine... Strange things happens sometimes ^^

Comment: Using alias may be useful too.

Comment: The first suggestion gets complicated when selecting from multiple tables / JOINs. However the second one with the wildcard * first is the life saver